# How to interprete $f(\bar z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How do i interprete $f(\bar z)$?

Is there any relationship between $f(z)$ and $f(\bar z)$?

For example, if $f(z)$ is analytic on domain $D$, then under what conditions are $f(\bar z)$ analytic?

Comment: For your example, $f(\bar z)$ is analytic if it is constant.

Comment: By Cauchy Riemann it is necessary that $\partial f(\bar z)/\partial {\bar z}=0$ if it is analytical.

Comment: is $z\cdot \bar z$ considered a function of $\bar z$?

Comment: @LittleRookie All complex functions can be thought of as functions of $z$ and $\bar z$ (just like they can be thought of as functions of $x=\Re(z)$ and $y=\Im(z)$... think of it as a change of coordinates). Holomorphic functions have trivial dependence on $\bar z.$ So your example $|z|^2 = z \bar z$ is not holomorphic. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives

Comment: @LittleRookie People are sometimes uncomfortable at this cause it seems like $z$ and $\bar z$ aren't independent. But consider that you can't reconstruct $x$ and $y$ in an algebraic way with just $z$ alone.. you need $\bar z$ too, e.g. $x = (z+\bar z)/2$

Comment: $\overline{f(\overline z)}$ is analytic when $f$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $f(\bar{z})$ stands for

> the image of the complex conjugate of $z$ under the function $f$

You might also see this notated as “$f(z^*)$” by [physicists or engineers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexConjugate.html).

In general, complex conjugation is [not analytic/holomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/28769/347062) ([synonyms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AnalyticFunction.html)) except in special cases as indicated in the comments.